# Questions when loading a .dat file into matlab variables

Tags: matlab, import, loading

Part of my .dat file looks like this:

```
1.916E+09   3.00  400.89  30.00  8.868E+05  1.848E+02  9.034E-05
1.916E+09   3.00  400.27  300.00  8.723E+05  1.860E+02  9.014E-05
1.916E+09   3.00  400.66  30.00  8.574E+05  1.873E+02  9.000E-05
```

.
.
.
.
.
.

It has 32 rows of data. Ideally I want to import the data with same format into a variable. I am using matlab 2013a and

I have tried data = load('filename')
--which prompt me: Error using load. Number of columns on line 2 of ASCII file must be the same as previous lines.

And I have tried data = load('filename') 
--which prompts me:
Undefined function 'readtable' for input arguments of type 'char'.

I am trying to use textscan but I couldn't figure out how to. I am new to matlab. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`load` only works on MATLAB formatted files.  They're also encoded in a proprietary way and because you're able to read your `.dat` file, it really isn't a MATLAB file then!  Also, `textscan` is certainly the way to go.  If your data is truly like that, then you can use `textscan` like so:

```
fid = fopen('mydata.dat');
C = textscan(fid, '%f%f%f%f%f%f%f');
fclose(fid);
```

Each row has 7 columns, and they all look like `double`s to me.  As such what `C` will return is a cell array of 7 elements.  Each cell will contain each column.

You would access the first column with `C{1}`, the second column with `C{2}` and so on.

Good luck!